# Почему не загружается с флешки?

Tags: windows

Пишу сюда, так как не нашел ничего подобного на просторах интернета. Суть проблемы в том, что у меня в один прекрасный момент вылез синий экран с текстом:»Recovery your pc/Device needs to be repaired...”.Я хотел снести винду и поставить заново, но тут облом флешка не загружается, вообще ноль реакции. Настроил, вроде, в биосе  все правильно ,смонтировал через руфус iso образ винды, но никакого толку.

Уже не в первый раз с такой проблемой сталкиваюсь, в прошлый раз оказалось, что на жестком диске не было вообще загрузочного разлела,  поэтому не загружалось ничего. В этот раз я не знаю, что происходит, но , надеюсь, вы сможете помочь.

Comment: зачем руфус, седьмая винда обычно записывается с помощью `Windows USB/DVD Download Tool`, а десятая и по моему восьмая пришется прямо сетапом

Comment: Что значит прямо сетапом?

Comment: ну там программа с сайта ихнего берется MediaCreationTool https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/software-download/windows10 и она либо ставит винду либо делает DVD или USB Flash